# Finding the $\angle STU$

Tags: geometry

In the given figure, $QS = QT$ and $RU = RT$. $\angle QPR=36°$. Find $\angle STU$.
[image]

Here, I took $\angle PQR=x$ and then tried to find the required angle but I couldn't get rid of the variable $x$.

The answer given is:

> $72° $

Comment: Picture shows $RU=UT$ not $RU=RT$.

Comment: Actually I mistook $QS=QT$ as $QS=QT$. That despite multiple times reading the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us assume the following notation:
\begin{align*}
\begin{cases}
x := \angle STU\\\\
y := \angle QST = \angle QTS\\\\
z := \angle RTU = \angle RUT
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

Since the inner angles of the triangle $\Delta PQR$ add up to $180°$, we may claim that
\begin{align*}
36° + (180° - 2y) + (180° - 2z) = 180° & \Longleftrightarrow 2y + 2z = 36° + 180°\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow y + z = 108°
\end{align*}

Given that $x + y + z = 180°$, we conclude that $x = 180° - 108° = 72°$.

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: Damn! Now I get the problem. I was repeatedly reading "QS=QT" as "QS=ST". That when I re-read 5 times. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: @InanimateBeing you are welcome! I am glad I could help.